# The Realm is already in a write transaction。

Tags: swift, realm

I ran into a "The Realm is already in a write transaction" error when running a Realm write operation on Swift. Therefore, I want to confirm when the write operation of Realm will cause this error to occur. Or can someone tell me some countermeasures? Thank you.

```
        if let model = searchWithPrimaryKey(modelType: T.self, primaryKey: primaryKey) as? T {

            try realm.write {

                action?(model)

            }

        }
```

Comment: Can you post a snippet of your code? Please read this before post some questions [How to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The error will be thrown when you attempt a write when already inside a write transaction, as shown by the error. Per the above, example code is needed. Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)